# Retrieving iPhone sms conversations

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I need to know how can I retrieve the native SMSes through my iPhone app. Any help will be much appreciated.

E.g. I launch my app and upon clicking a button want to retrieve some of the SMS conversations of a specific person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this. Unless you are running on a jailbroken device.

In future, please use the search function to avoid reposting questions that have already been asked and answered many many times.